Deterministic online caching algorithm competitive ratio lower bound proof
I don't understand the adversary based proof in CLRS for proving lower bound of Ω (k) on competitive ratio of any deterministic online caching algorithm given that cache size is k blocks.
Proof goes like this: Adversary constructs a request sequence to cause most amount of cache misses. Sequence of n requests where there are k+1 distinct blocks in the n requests is used to prove lower bound. Adversary causes n misses for any online deterministic algorithm but is only able to cause k + n/k misses for optimal greedy-choice based offline caching algorithm. (sidenote: I don't know why it isn't k + (n-k)/k misses for optimal algorithm).
In what sense is this the lower bound - wouldn't someone who is not an adversary give us a lower bound and someone who is an adversary should instead give an upper bound?
or do they mean lower bound in the sense that request sequence has only one more distinct blocks than the cache size?
